# OneToOne Mapping with Intermediate Table and Non Primary Keys

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have two tables that I would like to join with a @OneToOne mapping using an intermediate table, my problem is that it's not joined with Primary keys.

Here is my schema:

```
CREATE TABLE USERS
(
    USER_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    METADATA_ID INT NOT NULL,
    ...
);

CREATE TABLE USER_DETAILS
(
    USER_TYPE INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ..
);

CREATE TABLE USERS_METADATA
(
    ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    USER_TYPE INT NOT NULL,
    ...
);
```

I would like my `User` Hibernate Pojo to look like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
class User {
   @Id
   @Column(name = "USER_ID")
   private long userId;

   @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinTable(name = "USERS_METADATA",
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ID", referencedColumnName = "USER_ID"),
      inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USER_TYPE", referencedColumnName = "USER_TYPE"))
   private UserDetails userDetails;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_DETAILS")
class UserDetails {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "USER_TYPE")
    private long userType;
}
```

I was trying to map it as `@OneToOne` association using a `@JoinTable`, but it fails since not all the columns involved are PKs, for historical reasons the tables cannot be altered.

The error I'm getting is:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: SecondaryTable JoinColumn cannot reference a non primary key
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What hibernate version do you use?

Comment: I tried to use your mapping in hibernate 5.4.4 and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the point in creating a joining table for one-to-one relationship? The only thing, that is needed for two tables to be joined using this relationship is a single foreign key.

I would suggest creating an id to `USERS` table in `USER_DETAILS`:

```
CREATE TABLE USER_DETAILS
(
    USER_TYPE INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    USERS_ID REFERENCES USERS(USER_ID),
    ..
);
```

And then join using this column:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="USERS_ID")
private UserDetails userDetails;
```

Comment: Yeah, that would work, but that's what I try to avoid.

Comment: @Shvalb but why? It's how it's designed commonly, more efficient than joining table. What you did is an antipattern.

Comment: Thank you! I will rethink my design for this.

Comment: @Shvalb no problem, consider upvoting if you find this answer helpful;>